# using Webview in react native to share live video from raspberry pi

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi Im trying to use webview to share live video in my android app from localhost:8000, Im capturing video with raspberry pi camera and than sharing it to localhost. On site it looks like this: [image]

BUT in my android app I can see just white screen, I have installed react webview, connected it and Im using correct IP, any idea what could be the problem?

```html
renderCamera = () => {
        return (<WebView
            source={{uri: "http://"+"mylocalip"+":8000"}}
            style={{flex: 1}}
            //javaScriptEnabled={true}
            //domStorageEnabled={true}
            //startInLoadingState={true}
        />);
}

<View style={styles.topContainer}>
       {this.renderCamera()}
</View>
```

Comment: I forget to say that my video is in .mjpg format

Comment: I have tried this example (https://www.stefangordon.com/render-mjpeg-streams-in-react-native/) with formatHTML() didnt work
I have also tried to directly link that stream with url like this: 
uri: "http://"+"mylocalip"+":8000"+"/stream.mjpg"
but it still doesnt work, all I can see is white blank screen

Comment: this is crazy, I have already tried so many things but it still doesnt work.
I have updated expo to new version
I have tried to webview different basic websites that should 100% work
I have tried different versions of react-native-webview 
I have tried it to physical device and emulator 
but still just white blank screen :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<View>
      <WebView
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
        startInLoadingState={false}
        contentInset={{ top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        source={{ uri: 'http://mylocalip:8000/stream.mjpg' }} />
    </View>
```

Comment: I have tried it but it still doesnt work, only white blank screen
renderCamera = () => {

        return (<WebView
            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
            scalesPageToFit={true}
            startInLoadingState={false}
            contentInset={{ top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            source={{ uri: 'http:/mylocalip:8000/stream.mjpg' }} />);

    }